# Would this be defined as a form of HeapSort?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, heapsort

So I was messing around with implementations of sorting, and figure it wouldn't hurt to try a basic implementation using ArrayLists and a simple Binary Search like so:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> binarySort(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Integer value : list) {
        int index = binarySearchPosition(sortedList, value);
        sortedList.add(index, value);
    }
    return sortedList;
}

public static int binarySearchPosition(ArrayList<Integer> list, Integer value) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = list.size();

    while(max - min > 1) {
        int mid = (int) Math.floor((max + min) / 2);
        if(list.get(mid) < value) {
            min = mid;
        } else {
            max = mid;
        }
    }

    if(max == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(list.get(min) < value) {
        return max;
    } else {
        return min;
    }
}
```

It behaves essentially the same as a HeapSort, but doesn't actually create a heap out of the data. Would something like this be defined as a form of HeapSort still or as something else?

Comment: I know you are thinking of ArrayLists, but you wrote this with List.  That means it could easily be a LinkedList, which would have a much different performance than you are expecting.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Fair enough. I updated the code to make sure it's an ArrayList to keep get at O(1) like I intended.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong since my algorithm analysis skills are a little rusty, but I think this implementation would have `O( log2(n!) )` wouldn't it? `log2(a) + log2(b) = log2(ab)`, and this implementation will do `log2(1) + log2(2) + ... + log2(n-1) + log2(n)` roughly.

Comment: Answering the question in the "answer" section as it's getting a bit too large for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, correct me if I'm wrong since my algorithm analysis skills are a
>   little rusty, but I think this implementation would have O( log2(n!) )
>   wouldn't it? log2(a) + log2(b) = log2(ab), and this implementation
>   will do log2(1) + log2(2) + ... + log2(n-1) + log2(n) roughly

Thankfully, you're wrong, it would be roughly O(n^2).

You see, the `list.add(index, value)` is O(n) just by itself, and you have to do that N times.  How you find the index is just overhead and the O(log2(n)) would get hidden the O(n^2).  This is why (for sorted array lists) it's often just easier to search the list, copying elements across.  The search is still 0(n), the copying doesn't increase it, and you do it for each of the N items to be inserted.

You are performing O(log2(n)) N times.  That would be O(nlog2(n)).  However, the `list.add(index, value)` is by itself an O(n) operation.  Statistically, one would expect it to move 1/2 of the N elements, and big-O notation will discard the 1/2.

So in the end you're operation is O(n^2 * log2(n)) which is slower than O(n^2).

Reasoning without the math, it roughly breaks down to:

1. N elements added one at a time O(n).
2. Moving 1/2 of the N elements O(n).
3. A binary search to find the insert index O(log2(n)).

Note that if you know you're already hitting O(n^2), you can avoid the extra effort of finding the index with a very simple algorithm:

```
Create a new array one element bigger.
for each element in the original array {
  if the element is smaller than the added item, copy it at the same index.
  if the element is same / larger than the added item, copy in the added item, and copy the rest of the elements from index to index+1.
}
```

As you can see it's one full loop through the array, which would have to be repeated N times, or O(n^2).

Your data structure isn't really a heap, but a sorted list.  It's a very good optimization to search sorted lists using a binary search.  It's just not going to reduce the need to walk a lot of the list on an insertion sort; because you're going to wind up copying 1/2 the items (if the array is large enough to hold the new items) or copying the whole list (if the array was sized to match the input).  Both of those scenarios means that this insertion support approach is going to be O(n^2) regardless of how you find the index of the insertion.

Now, if you had a linked list, the insertion becomes O(1).  However, to find the index becomes a walk from the root node, which itself is O(n) (again on average 1/2 of the nodes will be passed over).

Now heaps are a different thing; but, you know that because they don't produce sorted lists.

Comment: Ahhhh, I need to do my research into the behavior of the tools some more it seems. Didn't realize the `add()` method would run at `O(n)` for additions other than adding to the end of the list. Thank you for the information, it was very helpful.

Comment: @TimHunter You're welcome, and by now I hope you're well along your way on this one.